# JPA: Map a Map<Entity, List<Enum>>

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two Entities Users and Company. I have also the Enum Roles.
A user have a map containing a company as key and many roles as values.

```
//For example, the user ted can have the company masseka, gara, and many roles in each
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company_id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Map<Company,List<UserRoles>> rolesPerCompany;
```

What could I do to map correctly my MAP ?
Because, with this code, I got the error :

````
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.gara.bo.model.Place.company_id in com.gara.bo.model.GaraUser.rolesPerCompany```
````

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby

Comment: No, you cant map such a map with JPA. You need to think in terms of database tables first: how if this going to be stored in tables? Then you need to map those tables using JPA.

Comment: @JBNizet, I succeeded to map with Element collection                     `@ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "gara_developer_roles_per_company")
    @MapKeyColumn(name="company_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "company")
    private Map<Company,String> rolesPerCompany;` but I can't have multiple values for the same key. For example if i put `<TotoCompany, "OWNER">` the first time then I add  `<TotoCompany, "ADMIN">` the second time, ADMIN will replace OWNER in database. The solution will be to create a table Roles, but I don't want to create another table istend of using my RoleEnum